# Is there a way in dart to calculate the date for the last week as a maximum by describing popular words

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

i am using the following code

```
DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd("en_US").format((myDateTime)
```

that give me the following output (Date of writing my question)

```
Tuesday June 21 , 2022
```

well , now i don't want the previous `format` look like the previous output UNLESS if there is one week back as a maximum Period

for example i am looking for Format to Auto  describe days of the week by (names) like following.

Assuming today is Tuesday

```
output => 'now' (if 5 mins as maximum ) else output => 'Today'

 else:

output => 'yesterday' (if there one day back )
output => 'Sunday'
output => 'Saturday'
output => 'Friday'
output => 'Thursday'
output => 'Wednesday'

NOW finally we arrive to same day whish is Tuesday that means 1 week passed so i need output like my first format in my question 

output => 'Tuesday June 21 , 2022'

And so
 
 output => 'Tuesday June 21 , 2022'
 output => 'Monday June 20 , 2022'
 output => 'Sunday June 19 , 2022' ...... and so
```

in other words i only care of showing a week back in
their names only : now(if 5 mins as maximum) till A week back in
their names else `DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd("en_US").format((myDateTime)`

what is the easiest and best way to do it . thanks

Comment: There is no specific format string for the logic you described. You will need to write your own function from the pseudo code you already have. Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I got you , thank you @nvoigt